# Using terraform in private cloud

Tags: terraform

Is it possible to use terraform to manage deployments on private cloud. I have gone through their official documentations but could find any information around this. If it's possible then which [Provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/index.html) should I use?

Update: I've missed some details previously.
We're using kvm/qemu as hypervisor to create VM's.

Comment: When you say "private cloud" what do you mean? Are you deploying to OpenStack or VMWare or something else? What have you tried so far and where are you struggling specifically?

Comment: By private cloud I meat it is on self managed datacenter, it's not AWS/OpenStack.

Comment: What do you use as a hypervisor? Or is it all bare metal? Do you have an API for creating VMs or anything? If not then there's nothing Terraform can magically do to work against it.

Comment: we use kvm/qemu.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [`libvirt` provider](https://github.com/dmacvicar/terraform-provider-libvirt) that is able to manage resources in KVM and is listed on the [community providers page](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/type/community-index.html).